# Unable to install ROS on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
After following all the steps on ROS Wiki,

I get stuck on

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

I get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to fix dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have also tried

```
sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
```

Nothing has worked.

Ouput of:

```
uname -m
x86_64
```

I didn't try

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

Because it can break X-Server.

What to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258319/unable-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-14.04.5/) by [jaskaranvirdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29882/jaskaranvirdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed libboost1.54-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-dev
```

And after that did the full install. It worked.

---

Originally posted by [jaskaranvirdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29882/jaskaranvirdi/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcamarneiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27884/mcamarneiro/) on 2017-09-26**:
DIdn't work